# What causes glTexSubImage1D() - GL_INVALID_VALUE error in this example when loading a texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to load a transfer function as 1D texture as follows:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, transfer);
glTexStorage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 1, GL_RGBA32F, 11);
glTexSubImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 1, 0, 11, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, props.transColors);
```

where `props.transColors` is a float array (these values can be changed from the GUI during runtime):

```
float transColors[4 * 11] = 
{
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};
```

The plan was to load the array as a 1D texture every frame using `glTexSubImage1D()`.

The function `glTexSubImage1D()` will always throw an GL_INVALID_VALUE error. From the documentation, the error can be cause because of one of the following reasons:

> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if level is less than 0.
>
> GL_INVALID_VALUE may be generated if level is greater than log2 max,
>   where max is the returned value of GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE.
>
> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if xoffset<−b, or if
>   (xoffset+width)>(w−b), where w is the GL_TEXTURE_WIDTH, and b is the
>   width of the GL_TEXTURE_BORDER of the texture image being modified.
>   Note that w includes twice the border width.
>
> GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if width is less than 0.

I don't think any of the listed points applies to my case. So I'm wondering, what causes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter (after `GL_TEXTURE_1D`) is the mipmap level. Level 0 is the largest mipmap level. Your image is allocated with one level (that's the second parameter to `glTexStorage1D`) but you are trying to upload the second level (since they start at 0). Pass 0 to `glTexSubImage1d` as the level number instead of 1.

Even if your texture did have more than one mipmap level, the data you're uploading would be too big for the second level.

Comment: Thanks, the error is now gone. If I may ask an additional question. I planned to call `glTexSubImage1D()` within the render loop, to update the texture values (along with `glUniform1i(location, 0)`, `glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)`, and     `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, transfer)` ). Is this the correct approach to update the data?

Comment: @RolandDeschain Yes it is. The value which has to be set to the texture sampler uniform is the number of the texture unit (0 for `GL_TEXTURE0`, 1 for `GL_TEXTURE1`, ...). The uniform is default initialized by 0, so it is not necessary to set 0 explicitly.